# Why does the UDP writer dial?

Tags: sockets, go, udp

I come from a C background and from my understanding, UDP is a connection-less protocol which, I assume, means that packets can't be sent without making a connection first. However, as I have gotten into Go and started writing networking code. I realised that Go's UDP writer dials a host before sending packets to it. Why is that?

Comment: ["Dial connects to the address on the named network."](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Dial) What's confusing about that?

Comment: It executes a syscall to open a network socket for the UDP "connection", and gets a file descriptor back which is wrapped in a `net.Conn` for use. It uses dial/connection semantics because that is how the underlying OS network stack operates.

Comment: https://golang.org/src/net/udpsock_posix.go?h=dialUDP#L97

Comment: The POSIX socket api has "connected" UDP sockets, so `Dial` is exactly the same as you would get via the `connect` syscall in C.

Comment: @Adrian you don't need an IP address and port number to open a UDP socket, atleast, not in C...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UDP *is* connectionless, at least in principal (implementations vary).  But there's still an implementation detail to worry about: to send a UDP packet (datagram) from "me" (my IP host and port addresses) to "you" (your IP host and port addresses), I must, at the least, specify your IP-and-port.  The same goes in reverse if and when you want to send a datagram to me.

Depending on the underlying OS, you or I *may* be able to do this with a `sendto` system-call.  That is, we start with a `socket` system call, then use a `sendto` system call to fire-and-forget: the datagram goes off, or doesn't, and we never bother to see what happens next.  The `sendto` call takes a destination address, which for TCP or UDP, supplies the IP address and port.

Or, we may use a `socket` system call, followed by an optional `bind` system call, followed by a `connect` system call.<sup>1</sup>  The `bind`, if we do it, establishes our local port (and maybe IP address, if we have more than one) and the `connect` establishes our destination IP address and port.  Now we can send packets with `write` or `send` system calls.

(Some systems add `sendmsg` and other such calls, which are generally supersets of all of the above and therefore can be used without a preliminary `connect`.  But *all* systems that support TCP have the concept of creating a network connection and bind-and-or-connect-ing and then writing data.)

One least-common-denominator setup, which is also pretty useful, is to assume that you'll specify your remote peer address at the time you want to create a network connection.  To do that in Go, use `Dial`.  Even if your underlying system has, say, only raw IP sockets, the library could build UDP atop those and provide the `Dial` interface, and that would then still work in Go.

---

<sup>1</sup>Ideally, this probably should have been an "establish peer information" system call, providing *both* local *and* remote addressing information, plus any optional flags.  Omitting a remote specifier would mean "listen to all incoming connections from everyone".  That would have eliminated the need for the `SO_REUSEADDR` flag, which exists just because it's otherwise impossible to distinguish between a `bind` that comes before a `connect`, or a `bind` that comes before a `listen`.  But it's a little late to fix 4.2BSD now.

Comment: I find it confusing that Golang keeps a connection state for a connectionless protocol. The whole `Dial` interface makes it hard to send messages to multiple hosts at once with a single socket. Moreover, does `Dial` ever fail for a UDP connection considering that, in theory, there's no need to establish set connection successfully? What would be an efficient way of sending UDP packets across multiple hosts at once?

Comment: @Whiteclaws: what torek is getting at is that this mirrors the underlying OS. You're understanding of the C api is incomplete, and you can create a "connected" UDP socket, which may behave slightly differently (for example, a connected socket may only return packets from the established remote host).

Comment: @Whiteclaws: if you're willing to bypass all the good stuff Go does for you, you can get a raw OS socket and call the raw OS `sendto` system call directly. There are a number of obstacles here (of varying difficulty levels), and if you do this, your Go program won't run on *other* OSes. Note that the Go ecosystem includes wrapping OS sockets in non-blocking behavior for better goroutine performance.

Comment: @Whiteclaws, perhaps you’re missing the fact that you create an ordinary unconnected UDP socket using [`ListenUDP`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#ListenUDP)

Comment: I would add that since some version of Go, every "standard" connection type from the `net` package (`IPConn`, `TCPConn`, `UDPConn`) supports the `SyscallConn` method which allows getting one's hand on a very thinly wrapped underlying socket—[`syscall.RawConn`](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#RawConn) which basically allows one to call arbitrary `fcntl`s on the socket as well as doing "raw" reads and writes on it.

Comment: @kostix: according to the linked page, it was new in 1.9. I managed to miss it. Nice to know it's there, for various special purpose hacks.

Comment: Yeah, precisely :) — to obviate the need for nifty hacks like [this one](https://github.com/libp2p/go-reuseport). IIRC, an umbrella issue which resulted in the current approach and implementation was [#9661](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9661).

Comment: @torek is the second "fire-and-forget" behavior available through raw sockets?

Comment: @Whiteclaws: if you use the `syscall.RawConn` trick to grab hold of a UDP socket before it's connected, you could then do a bunch of `syscall.Sendto` or `syscall.Sendmsg` operations before the dial code does a `connect`. Whether this works at all on Windows, I don't know; on BSD-derived systems and Linux, it should.

Comment: Meanwhile, as JimB noted, you could use `ListenUDP` to create a socket that's bound but not connected. You could then use the `RawConn` `Write` method to do `syscall.Sendto` etc. Again, it's not obvious whether this works on every OS.

Comment: @torek this doesn't seem to be a very trivial matter in Go and looks like it isn't the intended way of doing things, very well, I guess...